# adb has stopped working in android studio

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to build my first app in android studio and getting an error "adb.exe has stopped working". I am working on Windows xp 32 bit system.

[image]
Have tried several solutions available online including
-kill server/restart
-updating platform tools folder
-adding 127.0.0.1 as exception to be allowed
Still nothing seems to work out. Kindly help!!!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss a .dll file, this file **api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll** from your Windows 32-Bit system, just download that file according to your system and Copy/Paste the file to C:\Windows\System32

You can download it from here:
https://www.sts-tutorial.com/sites/downloadCenter.php?api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0

Comment: This worked for the previous error. but now i am getting a new error "Emulator: D:\AndroidStudio\sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: Could not load library WinHvPlatform.dll.

 Emulator: D:\AndroidStudio\sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: failed to initialize WHPX: Function not implemented"

Comment: The following Windows update (KB2999226) helped me on a Windows 8.1 machine: https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=49081

Comment: It didn't worked for me. Also tried reinstalling Android Studio, SDK, platform-tools, tried reinstalling c++ redistributable; nothing worked. What worked for me is copying adb.exe from one of my colleague's system.

Comment: @zoti I have the same problem. I did as you said but still, I am getting error messages "adb.exe has stopped working"

Answer (score 2):

The platform tools now depend on the Windows Universal C Runtime, which is usually installed by default via Windows Update. This is required [from 28.0.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools#2802_march_2019) (March 2019).

So if you are on an older version of windows or unable to update your windows, you must use an older version of platform-tools.

> **How to install the older version of platform tools?**

**1.** Delete all files from your `your-sdk-location\platform-tools`

**2.** Download platform tools version 28.0.1 from [here](https://devfiles.co/download/krSx7fxs/platform-tools-windows-latest.zip). Extract and copy all those files to `your-sdk-location\platform-tools`

Comment: Or simply update Universal C Runtime from windows https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

Download fresh adb files
File names in the zip files will be:

1. adb.exe
2. AdbWinApi.dll
3. AdbWinUsbApi.dll
4. fastboot.exe
   Go to C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools and paste these four files. (replace the old one).
   It will work fine

Download here 
https://androidstudio.io/downloads/tools/download-the-latest-version-of-adb.exe.html

Answer (score 1):

below solution work for me,

1. go to control panel and remove all adb.exe
2. in case still error window (adb.exe has stopped working error) -> go to Android Studio > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Untick "Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging" (this checking physical device or not, remember tick again in future when required).
   hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command before adb start

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, Downloading latest [SDK platform tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) and extracting it into platform-tools of your SDK location

You can know your SDK path from Android studio >> Tools >> SDK Manager >> Android SDK Location

Answer (score 0):

The missing dll file is located in the Java installation folder. Add it as a system PATH variable and reboot.
Example location C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\bin

Answer (score 0):

Updating the **Windows Universal C Runtime** fixed it for me.

Get the update from [microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows)