# "adb.exe has stopped working" error in android studio 4

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7, adb, android-studio-4.0

I am using Windows 7 Professional 32 bit os on my Laptop. I have downloaded Android Studio 4. When I open the android studio, I get an error in every two seconds "`adb.exe has stopped working`".

I have browsed other [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784292/adb-has-stopped-working-in-android-studio) and I tried all the suggestions but I am still getting the same error.

What I have tried:

1. Downloading  `api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll` from  https://www.sts-tutorial.com/sites/downloadCenter.php?api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0 and pasting the DLL file to `C:\Windows\System32`.
2. Typing `taskkill /f /im adb.exe` in command prompt.
3. Replacing the "platform-tools" folder with the new one  downloaded from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip

Even after trying the above-mentioned things, I am continuously getting the error.

Please suggest what can I do.

Also, I am getting an error in the console that "`daemon is not running`". Suggestions on this problem are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you are trying to run Android Studio on an x86 OS and the system requirements, as showing here, [Android Studio Download Page](https://developer.android.com/studio) are a bit different:

Microsoft® Windows® 7/8/10 (64-bit)
4 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended
2 GB of available disk space minimum,
4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution

Comment: I know that the system requirements are the ones on the download page are different, but if it is strict to 64-bit os only, then the android studio application itself would not have started, but it is working fine except this error. When I try to open or install an app which is only for 64-bit os, then I get an error message that "this app is not designed for your OS. Try installing a version which is compatible with your system". But when I installed android studio I didn't any error like this. So I think it is not related to 32-bit or 64-bit.